# Prevent overflow of items from the right side

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Is it possible to restic the overflow mechanism to not overflow from the right side in Internet Explorer 11?

I have the following setup:

```css
.overflow-container {
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 8rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.overflow-childs {
  display: flex;
  float: right;
  background: yellow;
}
.child {
  background: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.hidden {
  background: green;
  order: -1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="overflow-container">
    <div class="overflow-childs">
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child"></div>
      <div class="child hidden"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Do I need to change something? I tried to set `position:absolute` with `right:0` to the `overflow-childs` element but it doesn't work.

Comment: first, overflow hidden is a very bad idea... it removes the scroll ability not the ability to still overflow the screen. You simple cant scroll then to see the content. Next, simply define a a max width or exact width like body width 100% and then all element within a width of auto. That way it stays responive to the screen size but will not overflow to the sides. For  your design with a fixed width in pixels you have to add media queries and define breakpoints where the design changes if the screen size gets to small.

Comment: I'm using element.getBoundingClientRect() so I can add functionality when .child element left position is smaller than .overflow-container right